# Calculate standard deviation of same text values between cells in same column

Tags: excel, vba, macos, text, standard-deviation

The last few days I have been trying to create a macro in Excel which can calculate standard deviation which will take values from column B of same text values between different cells in column A and give the result in corresponding cell in column C. In my sheet there are lots of different text values in column A and corresponding value in column B. I want to take all values of column B from first row to last row of corresponding same text in column A and calculate the standard deviation of these values and shows the result in column C.

As an example, when it starts from first cell (aass) then it has to count all `aass` and take values from corresponding cell of column B after that calculate standard deviation. Please help me out.I will be happy to hear from you guys. I am trying to show how my sheet which will look like as below:

```
column A  column B  column C
text       value    result(standard deviation)
aass       112      35.16
aadd       243      12.9
ffdd       523      108.55
aass       198      35.16
aadd       252      12.9
aass       136      35.16
ffdd       342      108.55
ffdd       312      108.55
aadd       222      12.9
aadd       255      12.9
ffdd       322      108.55
aass       112      35.16
jjhgf      487      25.8
pouwe      565      6
jjhgf      451      25.8
jjhgf      424      25.8
qwert      643      0
pouwe      553      5
qwert      643      0
.....      ....    ...
.....      ....    ...
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and where you have run into trouble.

Comment: Also, please explain how you get the result of `108.55` for `ffdd`; and `5` for `pouwe`.  I get `86.27` and `6` respectively using the `STDEVP` function, although most of the other results are close to what you show.

Comment: you are correct. I am wrong with these two ffdd and pouwe result. Actually I did these calculation manually.I have a little knowledge on VBA and I am started to learn VBA. But in my office I have to do this calculation frequently .For that reason I want to write a macro in excel.If you can help me i will be grateful to you.@RonRosenfeld

Comment: This is not a codewriting service.  You already have two formula approaches -- see my comment in ZygD's answer.  I don't understand why you need a VBA approach.  But if you must, start off by developing an outline or algorithm; then code it; then post the code here if you run into trouble, and someone will help you review it.

Comment: I got your point and thanks for your help.It would be better if I post my try .i will try best to post code where I am facing trouble .Actually I have to do also other calculation side by side with standard deviation. that is the reason for VBA.@RonRosenfeld

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  So maybe when I see your code what you are trying to do will be more clear.  From what you have written so far, I think the best solution would be formulas in a Table with structured references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you what I mean by a Table with structured references.
I copied your data for the `text` and `value` columns.  I also added the header: `Result` to cell `C1`.

I then selected the Table option from the Insert ribbon (on the Tables tab)

[image: Insert Table]

I then entered this formula in `C2` as an array formula, confirming it by holding down <kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=STDEVP(IF(Table1[[#This Row],[text]]=[text],[value],""))
```

Excel automagically copied that formula down to the last row and produced the requested results.  If you now add a row, the table will extend (including the formula).  You can also add columns with different formulas.

In the formula above, `Table1[[#This Row],[text]]` refers to the context of the text column only on the row containing the formula, and `[text]` by itself refers to the entire text column; `[value]` refers to the entire value column.

The autoextension, and the ability to use the actual column labels is a desireable feature of Excel tables and structured references.  It is similar to having dynamic named ranges, but easier to implement.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much.I think it will work.But unfortunately its not working in my pc.I don't know why, may be my process was not correct.I get everything except one point. After selecting the table then I select cell C2 and then I past this formula in C2.After that I press  buttons ctrl+shift+down arrow+ enter.but after that an error is showing.please tell me whether I am correct or wrong?and what do you mean by "entered this formula in C2 as an array formula"?I will be happy tohear from you.Thanks in advance.@ronrose

Comment: Why are you including the down arrow? Where did you see that written? So far as the definition of an array formula, I suggest you do both an internet search and also examine the help topics in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I used without VBA. This is an array formula (entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) which resides in cell C1:

```
=STDEV(IF($A$1:$A$9=A1,$B$1:$B$9))
```

(In in my example file I have only 9 rows of data.)

In newer versions of Excel you can use this:

```
=STDEV.S(IF($A$1:$A$9=A1,$B$1:$B$9))
```

For the entire **population** use this:

```
=STDEVP(IF($A$1:$A$9=A1,$B$1:$B$9))
```

or

```
=STDEV.P(IF($A$1:$A$9=A1,$B$1:$B$9))
```

The following versions will be MUCH SLOWER:

`=STDEV(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))` ,  `=STDEV.S(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))` ,

`=STDEVP(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))` , `=STDEV.P(IF(A:A=A1,B:B))`.

[image]

Comment: From his results, it appears the values represent the entire population, rather than a sample.

Comment: dear, i am thankful to you and appreciate your answer.But I need VBA solution because my data is not fixed.I want to calculate it automatically.I will be happy if you can give the solution in VBA.@zygd

Comment: @Md.AbdurRahim The formulas will update whenever you change the data.  Just either make the range larger than it needs to be, or use a dynamic name, or, probably best, put the data in a table, which will update as you add rows, and use structured references.

Comment: What do you mean that your data is not fixed? **a)** values in Columns A or B change; **b)** number of values in Columns A and B change?

Comment: This is also true that it only gives result of entire population.@RonRosenfeld

Comment: I think I could not make you understand .I want to calculate standard deviation of all same text value like aass individually ,then ffdd then aadd .all the result will be different.As per i know your answer is giving the result of entire population from 1st row to 9 and you can also again read my question .Thanks in advance.@ZygD

Comment: Please, take a look at the screenshot. You can copy paste that formula down and the formula will change automatically, so all the results in different rows represent relevant values from the same row in column A.